# Customizing simple_form boolean input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

To add some markup to a boolean input (checkbox), I am trying to create a custom input like this:

```
class BooleanWithIconInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  def input(wrapper_options)
    super
  end
end
```

The problem is, that this input is already displayed differently, since it is missing a `<div class="checkbox">` container and it adds classes like `control_label` and `form_control`.

Why is that happening, and how can I get the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

in the `initializers/simple_form.rb` file you can already make some adjustments: For example default would be

```
  # Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
  # Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
  #   inline: input + label
  #   nested: label > input
  config.boolean_style = :nested
# You can wrap a collection of radio/check boxes in a pre-defined tag, defaulting to none.
  # config.collection_wrapper_tag = nil
  # You can wrap each item in a collection of radio/check boxes with a tag,
  # defaulting to :span.
  # config.item_wrapper_tag = :span
```

If this does not help you the simple_form documentation has some detailed docs on how to individualize markup.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

I know this is just an easy tip. Unfortunately, I can not help out now with a custom solution. Hope it helps. I might have a deeper look at this later...